# Where can I find an overview of all my comments?

Tags: support, comments

My co-worker posted a question, and I commented on it.  But afterwards I have a hard time finding it.  I would imagine it should be on my profile page, but it only has my questions and my answers.  Does such an overview not exist, or am I missing something here?

Comment: see the "all actions" tab

Answer (score 6):

You can find this in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6147663/brian-clink?tab=activity&sort=comments). You can either follow that link directly, or navigate to your profile by clicking on your avatar in the top bar

Click on the Activity tab at the top, then scroll down to "All Actions" and select "Comments".

[image: All Actions -> Comments]

Comment: @BrianClink it will only be visible if the related post or the comment is not deleted